# How to create shortcuts for color changes in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shortcuts, palette

In Illustrator or InDesign, there are keyboard shortcuts to quickly change the color attributes of the object:

- <kbd>D</kbd>: Default (no fill, black stroke)
- <kbd>X</kbd>: Exchange (activates fill or stroke, whichever was not selected)
- <kbd>Shift+X</kbd>: Exchange (swaps the fill/stroke values)
- <kbd>/</kbd>: None (sets fill/stroke to none)
- <kbd>,</kbd>: Applies last used color
- <kbd>.</kbd>: Applies last used gradient

I search in the [Inkscape keyboard and mouse reference](https://inkscape.org/doc/keys.html#idm630) but it seems to not support this. If so, is there a way to assign color changing shortcuts in Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as far as I know, although maybe somebody could script it (well beyond my abilities sadly) . . . however

You can swap the fill and stroke in Inkscape by right clicking the Fill or Stroke colour boxes (bottom left of the application window), and choose Swap Fill and Stroke from the popup, or choose any of the other actions. There are no shortcuts for any of these.

[image]

Another possibly helpful function is to double click any of the drawing tools in the toolbar to bring up the preferences for that tool, and choose "Last used Style" in the options. Again there's no shortcut for this.

[image]

From here you can also use "This tools own style", and hit "Take from Selection" to create a default style for a tool.

If you have some gradients set up, you can easily flip between them by selecting an object, hit <kbd>G</kbd> to select the Gradient tool, then in the Tool Controls along the top you can select from the gradients you've already created.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why the Inkscape devs don't implement this?

Comment: @Ooker To be honest, not sure if anyone but Illustrator users would miss these shortcuts. I prefer to think of Inkscape as its own thing, not something that's merely an imitation of Illustrator. IMHO it's the differences with Inkscape that I appreciate, and which make Inkscape better for some tasks, such as creating SVGs. Personally I wouldn't want Inkscape to be like Illustrator.

Comment: I understand and agree with that. However, I think if a feature is useful, then the act of implementing it is irrelevant with Illustrator from the beginning. For example the selector has its own shortcut, and we don't say it is to imitate Illustrator. Why isn't changing color as useful as other features to have its own shortcut?

Comment: @ooker I can't really answer that. I'm not a developer. It may not be on their priority list. You could always make a feature request.